# Where to ask a question regarding programming from a business perspective?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked a question on Stack Overflow about what I need to do to prepare to freelance/consult.  It was closed by the mods, but I'm not sure where I should go to ask this type of question?

It is programming related but not necessarily programming, I can see why it doesn't necessarily fit on SO but don't know where to go to ask this.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471942/how-to-set-myself-up-tax-wise-to-consult-w-2s-1099s-llc-s-corps) to question (10K).

Everyone else:

> I'm going to start doing some freelance/consulting work outside of my
>   normal job. I've never done this before so I'm not sure how I need to
>   set myself to do this?
>
> They will make me a vendor and give me a 1099 at the end of the year I
>   think. Do I need to do anything special beyond this? We are not
>   talking about a lot of hours, I think 20-30 total.
>
> I'd be interested in any input from current freelancer/consultants.
>   Are you a LLC, S-corp? How do you handle taxes and payments? Did any
>   of this cost you money to setup?

Is there a Stack Exchange Community for this already?

Comment: Deleted it so you wouldn't attract 20 more downvotes.

Comment: @Won't: Why didn't you just lock it?

Comment: @Martin: Because it was crying out for deletion anyway?

Answer (score 7):

Don't ask on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) either.

It *might* be OK for [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com), however, it might well be too localised for there anyway so check by searching for similar questions before posting.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur This question is not appropriate for OnStartups either. It is way too broad. You need to do some initial research on your own so you can ask a more specific question. (I'm a mod on OnStartups.)

Comment: @Zuly - It's a tough questions to research, there are so many type of 'contract' work from trades to software, and there are many site that just want money to help you set up an LLC...  I'm trying to filter good research from bad.   It seems SE is not the place for these types of questions, which is okay, I was just hoping for some insight or a solid direction to help refine my searching.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur - if all you're doing is 20-30 hours work **TOTAL**, then I can pretty much tell you for sure that you need to do nothing special.  Your tax person can help you declare that 1099 income at the end of the year.  If you were working **full-time** on a 1099 you *might* have to make advanced payments to the IRS, but a tax person would be able to tell you more.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Don't take this the wrong way, but it doesn't look like you've done any research at all. The issue with your question is that you have several unrelated questions that are all very broad. You need to take each one separately and research it independently before you can ask a less broad question. Maybe [my answer here](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/13694/can-you-recommend-one-or-two-books-that-will-explain-the-process-of-creating/13704#13704) will help you get started.

Comment: @Zuly - Thanks.  I will definitely read that, I didn't know about the StartUps SE site until today.  (one of the problems with SE is that the knowledge is often spread out too wide to make it easy to find).  I appreciate the input.  This is a brand new venture to me so my questions are probably overly noobish.

Answer (score 2):

Ask it nowhere.  There are no SE sites in existence to give you legal advice, which is what your question is seeking.

Find yourself a tax professional, and ask him or her.

Comment: I don't believe that I cannot ask fellow programmers about their experiences as a freelancer/consultant.  I understand for 100% legal guarantees to what Im asking that is my best bet.  But I'm looking more to get info about the process, what people would have done differently, better, what order... anything they didnt think of that is necessary.  Telling me to go to a tax person would be like telling everyone on SO to go to the vendor or software maintainer to get programming answers to their specific language.  I fully understand YMMV with any answer you get from a SE site.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur - if it were up to me, I'd make questions like that ok for Programmers.SE, but they're very very strict.  Don't get me started.  Just throw it up on OnStartups like Chris said and see where that gets you.

Comment: I completely understand.  Maybe a side discussions is why do they have `freelance` and `consulting` tags on SO.  It would seem that both of those would never apply to a valid question there.  Thanks.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur - the freelance tag is indeed a problem.  See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123699/burninate-the-freelance-tag

Comment: -1000 for "Just throw it up on OnStartups like Chris said and see where that gets you." I left a comment saying it was not a good fit for OnStartups, and I'm a mod, so it won't get him very far.

Comment: @Zuly - -1000 for not realizing that I posted that comment before reading yourss.  Geez.  Calm down.  Please.

Comment: According to the timestamps on our comments it would have been impossible for me to know that you posted your comment before reading mine. In any case, I'm not actually upset. I'll direct my fake wrath towards @ChrisF for being the first to suggest OnStartups :-)