# Burninate the freelance tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It looks like the [freelance](/questions/tagged/freelance) tag is attracting more noise than signal.  It also tricked the OP of [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123687/where-to-ask-a-question-regarding-programming-from-a-business-perspective/) into thinking that his question was appropriate (based on his comment)

Should it stay?

[image]

Comment: There are 53 open `[freelance]` questions. I voted to close 51. __The other two seemed salvageable__, so I edited them instead.

Comment: @Popular - there are a lot fewer now ...

Comment: @PopularDemand Thanks.  I agree, those two looked worth salvaging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, what a mess.  Most of the questions tagged [freelance](/questions/tagged/freelance) were already closed for various reasons, so it wasn't a hard decision to delete the vast majority of them.  As mentioned in the comments above, [Popular Demand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131713/popular-demand) edited two of them into shape, and I removed the tag from those.

Of the rest I closed and deleted all but one that had already been locked.  [What should every developer know about legal matters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1396191/1288) is off-topic, but I think the top answer is good enough that it should be preserved.  (Somewhere... I'm trying to find it a permanent home.)

So anyway, the [freelance](/questions/tagged/freelance) tag has been burnninated.

[image]

Comment: Great work, Bill.  I'd love to mark this answer as accepted, but I think it's...[missing something](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80295/155403)

Comment: @AdamRackis Jeff is the one who always burninates tags and now he's leaving.  :'(

Comment: I think we need a mod to fill those shoes...Trogdor's hungry...wanna feed him???

Comment: @AdamRackis Alright... I'll do it.