# Where to ask for advice on software projects

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

Is there a community here on the Stack Exchange network or somewhere else on the internet where I can ask and receive answers questions such as:

If I needed to purchase 10 copies of Windows 10 Pro, what would be the best and cheapest way to go about it? Or, when upgrading a small business to allow some of their users to utilize remote desktop to login to their network, is their current network firewall going to be enough or would you need/want to set up a VPN?

Etcetera.  I've asked these questions before and have been downvoted into the ground and maybe if I ask the question about the question here, in meta, I might get a useful answer.  I am fully aware the answer may be "No - you don't ask that here, or anywhere on StackExchange", which is fine.

Thank you for your time

Comment: There was [nothing here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=where+ask+computer+question) (possibly add a word or two)?

Comment: Rob - you're right, I did find the following that seems like what i'd be asking: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123687/where-to-ask-a-question-regarding-programming-from-a-business-perspective

Comment: I should have stated my overall intent is to obtain some kind of validation for software consulting strategies, and basically ask where to get the best deals / best approaches for solving problems, like upgrading businesses infrastructure and deploying / developing applications

Comment: For example, if I google "Windows 10 Pro" and just buy 10 copies from the first link I see that looks reasonable - but then later someone says to me "why didn't you go to X website that bundles these things for you" - then not only do I feel stupid, but the client is out money. I don't want to make the mistake if there's something obvious I'm missing and it isn't something that necessarily comes up with a keyword search

Comment: The *problem* with your question is that you've asked 4 questions: "Buy Win 10 Pro",  "Upgrade to remote login", "current network vs. VPN" & etc. - one site won't provide the best answer. The search suggestion may help. Your question might be closed for being too broad if you either are unable to answer part of it yourself or ask separate questions. I suspect each individual question has an answer already, in which case they are dupes. Since I have enough time to offer a helpful search tip I did so, researching to determine ***if*** they are dupes goes beyond the time I have available ATM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem with things like that is that its deeply subjective, and kinda falls between the cracks of what's on topic.

Its essentially a *product, service or learning material* and that's off topic on most conventional sites. Its also off topic on *software recs* since you're asking on the where and should I, rather than the what would do the job.

So for the *first* class of questions, its probably off topic anywhere on the network.

> when upgrading a small business to allow some of their users to utilize remote desktop to login to their network, is their current network firewall going to be enough or would you need/want to set up a VPN?

Is trickier. Its somewhat subjective *but* could be massaged into a question. There's probably so many unknowns though - what the current firewall is, what the VPN is, and where you're actually running into trouble.

Rather than a "would I?" it would turn into a "I have this problem, how do I sort it out?" question.

Comment: I see what you mean - but by making it a specific question, I may miss the one person who will save me from doing stupid. For example, lets say I go ahead and set the client up with a VPN - then later I run into a problem and ask about it - and it comes out in the wash that it wasn't something I really needed / was overkill. I can't tell you how many times SO has saved my rear end from doing something that I really didn't need to do, or that there was a MUCH simpler or elegant way of doing.

Comment: But I am not arguing with you - I think what I need to do is find someone who's done freelance consulting, trap them in a room and bend their ear for an hour.  And maybe buy them a six pack to say I'm sorry.